# Is It possible to use the (multi-column) combobox controls from MS access in my VS c# winforms project?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, controls

Is It possible to use the (multi-column) combobox controls from MS access in my VS c# winforms project?

I'm looking for a tool-set or source-code of these acces controls. Or is MS to protective and there's just noway they will allow my to do something like this?
thnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Your best option is to use the WPF ComboBox control and create a template with multiple columns.  You can then import the WPF control into your winforms project by using an ElementHost.

Comment: Thnx! that will do just fine. I never used wpf only winforms but I guess this is as good a time as any.

Comment: Yes Winforms is fast becoming obsolete - WPF is much more powerful.  Unfortunately the learning curve is pretty steep but it's all worthwhile.  Good luck :)